# Failure from epel with yum command

Tags: pip, redhat, yum, epel

Thank you for coming to try to solve my problem. I have seen a lot of solutions about a failure using the yum command but until now, these solutions didn't work with me.

First of all, here is some information about the situation :
I'm working with a RedHat Linux 7.2-11, using a proxy (because of the very secured network of my firm) so I already modified etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date, etc/wgetrc and etc/yum.conf files with the http_proxy, proxy_user and proxy_password !

Then, I'm connected as root and I tried to download python-pip doing these command :

```
sudo yum install python-pip
```

I had the following error :

```
No package python-pip available
```

Exactly the same error when trying to install epel-release before python-pip.
Then I did the following :

```
yum install httpd php php-gd php-mysql
```

Finally, I downloaded and installed epel-release with these commands in /tmp :

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

Everything was ok !

Here is the problem. After that, I tried again these commands :

```
sudo yum install python-pip
sudo yum install -y python-pip
```

The first error was :

```
One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:
........some tips (1 to 5)........
Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again
```

So I followed some instructions and modified epel.repo and epel-testing.repo commenting all "mirror" lines and uncommenting all "baseurl" lines.
So, now, when I try to install python-pip again I have this error :

```
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 407 - Proxy Authentication Required
Trying other mirror.


One of the configured repositories failed (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

.........some tips (1 to 5).......

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from epel: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 407 - Proxy Authentication Required
```

Please do you know how to solve this issue, or do you have any idea ?
It seems to be because of the proxy but I already configured the three files as said on top of my message.

Thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to download `epel-release` manually on a CentOS-7 box. The latest RPM might be missing `mirrorlist` in the repo file, which is probably calling `baseurl=http://` rather than `mirrorlist=https://`.

Here is what you can do to resolve this:

```
 # Remove already installed epel-release
 yum remove epel-release
 OR
 rpm -e epel-release

 # Install epel-release using YUM
 yum install epel-release

 # Install python-pip
 yum install python-pip
~]# yum install python-pip
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                  |  11 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                 | 4.3 kB  00:00:00     
(1/3): epel/x86_64/group_gz                                                                                                                          | 170 kB  00:00:00     
(2/3): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                                                        | 769 kB  00:00:01     
(3/3): epel/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                        | 4.6 MB  00:00:06     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror.eboundhost.com
* epel: ftp.cse.buffalo.edu
* extras: repo.us.bigstepcloud.com
* updates: centos.mirrors.tds.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python2-pip.noarch 0:8.1.2-5.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python-setuptools for package: python2-pip-8.1.2-5.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-setuptools.noarch 0:0.9.8-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python-backports-ssl_match_hostname for package: python-setuptools-0.9.8-4.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-backports-ssl_match_hostname.noarch 0:3.4.0.2-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python-backports for package: python-backports-ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-4.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-backports.x86_64 0:1.0-8.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved


  Package                                                      Arch                                Version  

  Repository                     Size

Installing:
 python2-pip                                                  noarch                          8.1.2-5.el7                               epel                          1.7 M
Installing for dependencies:
 python-backports                                             x86_64                          1.0-8.el7                                 base                          5.8 k
 python-backports-ssl_match_hostname                          noarch                          3.4.0.2-4.el7                             base                           12 k
 python-setuptools                                            noarch                          0.9.8-4.el7                               base                          396 k

Transaction Summary
```

Comment: Hi iamauser ! Thank you. However, there is the same problem with epel-release than with python-pip : when I try "yum install epel-release" I have this error : "No package epel-release available. Error : Nothing to do". That's why I had to do it manually and unfortunately, it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Can you check if you have the section `extras` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`. If yes, then check it is enabled, if not run `yum --enablerepo=*extras* install epel-release`

Comment: Actually, I don't even have CentOS-Base.repo. I just found a solution adding the proxy in /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo. So I tried again yum install python-pip and it worked ! Nevertheless I will not be allowed to install superset with "pip install superset" (it was my first objective) because of the proxy of my firm. Someone just told me now... So, many thanks for your help !!